# Using glutIdleFunc to get out of glutMainLoop?

Tags: android, c++, opengl, glut

Im writing a programme that opens and openGL windows with an image and connects to my android device where the user uses the device as a sort of trackpad to pan and zoom in and out. All is working fine however the programme gets stuck in the glutMainLoop and will not proceed with accepting data from the device. Apparently glutIdleFunc is the solution to my problem however i cant see how to implement this in my code without getting a memory error? Could someone show me how to put the function into my code so it runs the connection code as well as the opengl stuff?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <vrpn_Shared.h>
#include <vrpn_Analog.h>
#include <vector>
#include <GL/freeglut.h>
#include <imageviewer.h>

using namespace std;

int done = 0;
int accepted = 0;           // Signals that the program should exit
unsigned tracker_stride = 1;    // Every nth report will be printed


//-------------------------------------
// This section contains the data structure that holds information on
// the devices that are created.  For each named device, a remote of each
// type analog is created.

class device_info {
    public:
    char            *name;

    vrpn_Analog_Remote  *ana;

};
const unsigned MAX_DEVICES = 2;


//-------------------------------------
// This section contains the data structure that is used to determine how
// often to print a report for each sensor of each tracker.  Each element
// contains a counter that is used by the callback routine to keep track
// of how many it has skipped.  There is an element for each possible sensor.
// A new array of elements is created for each new tracker object, and a
// pointer to it is passed as the userdata pointer to the callback handlers.


class t_user_callback {
    public:
    char            t_name[vrpn_MAX_TEXT_LEN];
        vector<unsigned>    t_counts ;
};

//Callback handlers

void    VRPN_CALLBACK handle_analog (void *userdata, const vrpn_ANALOGCB a)
{
    int i;
    const char *name = (const char *)userdata;

    printf("Input from %s:\n  \n        %5.0f", name, a.channel[0]);
    for (i = 1; i < a.num_channel; i++) {
    printf(" %5.0f \n", a.channel[1]);
    }
    printf(" \n");
}




int main (int argc, char * argv [])
{

  int   print_for_tracker = 1;  // Print tracker reports?
  int   print_for_button = 1;   // Print button reports?
  int   print_for_analog = 1;   // Print analog reports?
  int   print_for_dial = 1; // Print dial reports?
  int   print_for_text = 1; // Print warning/error messages?


  device_info device_list[MAX_DEVICES];
  unsigned num_devices = 0;


  int i;

  // Parse arguments, creating objects 

  for (i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
    if (!strcmp(argv[i], "-notracker")) {
      print_for_tracker = 0;
    } else if (!strcmp(argv[i], "-nobutton")) {
      print_for_button = 0;
    } else if (!strcmp(argv[i], "-noanalog")) {
      print_for_analog = 0;
    } else if (!strcmp(argv[i], "-nodial")) {
      print_for_dial = 0;
    } else if (!strcmp(argv[i], "-notext")) {
      print_for_text = 0;

    } else if (!strcmp(argv[i], "-trackerstride")) {
      if (tracker_stride <= 0) {
      fprintf(stderr, "-trackerstride argument must be 1 or greater\n");
      return -1;
      }
    } else {    // Create a device and connect to it.
    device_info *dev;



    // Name the device and open it as everything
    dev = &device_list[num_devices];
    dev->name = argv[i];

    dev->ana = new vrpn_Analog_Remote(dev->name);


    if (print_for_analog) {
        printf(" Analog");
        dev->ana->register_change_handler(dev->name, handle_analog);
    }
    printf(".\n");
    num_devices++;
    }

  }

 // main interactive loop

  printf("Press ^C to exit.\n");
  while ( ! done ) {
      unsigned i;

      // Let all the devices do their things
      for (i = 0; i < num_devices; i++) {

      device_list[i].ana->mainloop();

      glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGB | GLUT_SINGLE);
    glutInitWindowSize(400,300);
    glutInitWindowPosition(200,100);
    glutCreateWindow("ImageViewer");


    init();
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutMotionFunc(drag);
    glutMouseFunc(mouse);
 //   glutIdleFunc(IdleFunc);
    glutMainLoop();

      }
  }
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does GLUT work on Android and OpenGL ES?

Comment: Non of the image data is rendered on the device its all rendered on the PC. Im not sure what your asking Nicol?

Comment: Maybe he's writing game about androids and that explains tag?

Comment: Haha no im not at all. Ive now created 3 seperate accounts for this website and everytime ive asked a question ive recieved nothing helpful back. They have been school college level questions and no one could answer them? They may not be 100% clear or accurate but im very new to it. I give up with asking for help.

Comment: @Tom: Why are you creating multiple accounts?  That doesn't help you get answers.  Anyway, if your `IdleFunc` is causing a "memory error", you need to show its code.

Answer (score 1):

glut is fine if it can manage all of the input devices, and everything is event-driven from the inputs that it manages.  Once you have unmanaged input devices or non-event-based processing, you probably want to use something other than glut.  Your other alternative is to fork and run your asynchronous stuff in a separate process (or thread).